# The resistance piston on my exercise machine squeaks

Tags: maintenance, machine

Is it OK to lubricate these things.  If so with what?  If not does it mean my machine is on its last days?

It is a Cardio Glide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a manual that says to use household oil like WD-40 if it squeaks.